# Ubuntu server 14.04 Webmin installed

Tags: server, dns, email

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 server.  I am administering the domain from GoDaddy.  I would like to dump GoDaddy and use my Ubuntu server for everything including e mail and set up my own DNS from Ubuntu.  I am currently using DSN from my ISP.  I want to get stand alone as soon as possible.  Where should I start?

Answer (score 0):

For dns you could start with bind. Bind is software to setup your own nameserver.

For email you could take a look at Dovecot for imap/pop3 and postfix for smtp. Alternatively you could take a look at exim.

If you are planning on serving websites you can take a look at apache or nginx. (there are a lot of alternatives, look for which best serve your specific need). 
If you are hosting php, a lot of people go with the basic LAMP stack: Linux Apache Mysql/mariadb and php.

It will not be easy to learn all the settings for the software and the principles behind them all at once. But it is fun to do and very worthwile.

There are tons of tutorials on the web to install lamp with vhosts (if you want more then one domain on your server) and also some for bind.

Comment: I currently have LAMP installed and operational.  I am currently serving web content.  I have Webmin installed and wish to stick to it for configuration.  I now have a A record operational of abmail.archbrooks,us.  I have also submitted a new MX record but it has not propagated as of  now.

Comment: Keep in mind registrars might force you to a 2-name server setup - to provide a level of failover.  1&1, Gandi.net, and godaddy are examples of such registrars who complain...

Comment: In my particular situation I am stand alone.  The ISP does not become involved with anything I care to do with my server.  I have purchased this platform and I am free to make it do anything I am programmer enough to make happen.  I do not anticipate any complaints from the ISP at this time.  I will however keep you posted on all developments.